# Is it a compact set?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X:=C[0,1]$ is an metric space and $d(x,y)=\sup_{t\in[0,1]} |x(t)-y(t)|$ for $x,y\in X$. Then is $\bar B(0,1)$ closed and compact in $X$? I can prove that it is closed set by proving the complement is open. I think that it shouldn't be a compact set but not sure how to prove it. I know the definition of a compact set, that's any infinite open cover of a set has a finite subcover of that set.

Comment: See here for more detail:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207445/for-infinite-compact-set-x-the-closed-unit-ball-of-cx-will-not-be-compact

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217757/unit-sphere-not-compact-in-luenberger-page-40-opt-by-vector-space-methods

Answer (score 2):

From Riesz's Theorem we have known that

"A normed space $X$ is a finite dimensional if and only if its closed unit ball is compact".

We can prove that $C[0,1]$ is a normed space with the norm given by
$$
\|x\|=d(x,0), \quad \forall x\in C[0,1].
$$
Since $C[0,1]$ is an infinite dimensional space, its closed unit ball is not compact.

In $C[0,1]$ we can choose an infinite linear independent vectors as: $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n, \ldots\}$. Hence $C[0,1]$ is an infinite dimensional space.

For more detail, please see here

- [for infinite compact set $X$ the closed unit ball of $C(X)$ will not be compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207445/for-infinite-compact-set-x-the-closed-unit-ball-of-cx-will-not-be-compact)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217757/unit-sphere-not-compact-in-luenberger-page-40-opt-by-vector-space-methods

Comment: I am just a new learner of basic topology, i am not sure what is that theorem, is there any way make use of some basic topology definition and theorem to prove it?

Comment: @Mathematics: You can see the following references for a direct proof. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217757/unit-sphere-not-compact-in-luenberger-page-40-opt-by-vector-space-methods

Comment: @Mathematics: Dear Sir. Are you agree with my answer?

Comment: i am wondering how he construct that counter example from the property of the compactness and the metric is not the same as my question.

Comment: @Mathematics: You should modify the example to obtain your own solution.